# Python Django: Insert dynamic form records to db

Tags: python, django

It is a Medical Lab Software solution. A user makes lab investigation request that is unique to a patient’s encounter, I.e., a patient can have 1 or more request per encounter. This uniqueness is denoted by the encounter_id.
The challenge now is the ability to send the results back to the requester.

I am able to display all requests per encounter_id on a template but unable to return the result since each result is tied to a particular investigation. This is largely because I have a limited knowledge on JS. My current approach can only submit one record, usually the last record

Here’s the URL that displays the result template: https://smart-care.herokuapp.com/labs/lab_results/1/

Here’s the django template:

```
<div class="container">
    <form id="myForm" method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
       {% for request in lab_request %}
        {{ request.test }}: <input type="text" class="result" id="{{ request.test.id }}" name="test_id"> <br>
       {% endfor %} 
       <br><br>
       <button>Send Result</button>
    </form>
</div>

# Here’s my view:
def lab_results_view(request, enc_id):
    lab_request = LabRequest.objects.filter(encounter_id=enc_id, done=False, decline=False)

    if request.POST.get('test_id'):
    for req_id in request.POST:
        results = request.POST.get(req_id, False)
        print("results = ",results)

    template = "labs/lab_results.html"
    context = {"lab_request":lab_request}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

The models:

```
class LabRequest(models.Model):
    encounter = models.ForeignKey(PatientEncounter, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    patient          = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    test             = models.ForeignKey(LabTest, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    accepted         = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    decline          = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    done             = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_by       = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    date_created     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated          = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.patient.id)


class LabResult(models.Model):
    lab_request   = models.ForeignKey(LabRequest, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    result        = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    created_by    = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    date_created  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
    return str(self.result)
```

Thanks as I anticipate your kind response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that Django handles form elements based on `name` attribute and not the `id` attribute so this means you need to change name per request and on the view side you loop on all keys in request.POST like

```
for req_id in request.POST:
      result = Request.POST[req_id]
```

Edit: for the template

```
<div class="container">
      <form id="myForm" method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %} 
{% for request in lab_request %}
{{ request.test }}: <input type="text" class="result" id="{{ request.test.id }}" name="{{ request.test.id }}"> 
  <br> {% endfor %} <br><br>
  <button>Send Result</button>
 </form> </div>
```

Edit2: The view shall be like this

```
def lab_results_view(request, enc_id):
    lab_request = LabRequest.objects.filter(encounter_id=enc_id, done=False, decline=False)
    if request.method == "POST":
        for req_id in request.POST:
             results = request.POST.get(req_id)
              print("results = ",results)

template = "labs/lab_results.html"
context = {"lab_request":lab_request}
return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: thanks for your response,  I don't quite fully see into your response but I'll give it a try when I'm back on desk,  on weekend break now. Thanks.

Comment: pls i seem not to understand where your code comes handy, it returns when used but i made a few adjustments as:                                                                                      for req_id in request.POST:
      result = Request.POST.get(req_id, False). But this prints false. Where and how exactly am I suppose to apply this? please bear with me, I'm a beginner.

Comment: Can you share you updated template and view?

Comment: I haven't made any meaningful change to my view except that I commented what I had and tried to see what your suggested codes would result. In the end, it returned false. Can you kindly be a little detailed about  your first answer pls. As regards my template, nothing has changed. I'm quite stuck here . You may also wish to share a private chat with me on mails, whatsapp or any other means possible; kindly indicate if that's ok by you please. Thanks

Comment: See the updated view and template. The view returns "False"

Comment: Put for loop in view under if request.method ='POST'

Comment: Please see the updated view and template. It prints the last user input for the and results =  xC2WmB4RJZe8znpH8wdS2rGSIPvY1GeZ3BJKC9WbsF12tWikD6jBG8nrzoY7Vphc             You can click the URL added in the description above to see how the template renders. Only the last input is printed.

Comment: Check Edit2 in the answer

Comment: Thanks a bunch, perfect! Works just as needed. I want want to thank once again for your patience and tolerance.